# Kafka How to process non-duplicate and ordered messages

Tags: apache-kafka, ktable

can anyone please help. I have below requirement.

Requirement: Process non-duplicate, order chat-messages and make them a bundle per ProgramUserId, and here is the process and involved topics.

Data set up:
ProgramUserId can have any number of messages but each message is unique and has a composite key: MsgId + Action. So imagine data in kafka like this below.

P2->M3+A1  , P2->M2+A1  , P2->M1+A1  , P1->M3+A1 ,  P1->M2+A2 , P1->M2+A1 , P1->M1+A1

I am doing this right now:

**Initial-Topic**: (Original key: ProgramUserId)

1)From Initial-Topic --> consume Kstream ( with re-keying to : Msg Id + Action ) --> then write  to topic : **dedup-Topic**

2. From **dedup-Topic** --> consume Kstream  (with re-keying back to original key : ProgramUserId ) --> write  to topic:  **Final-Topic**

Since we are re-keying at the dedup-topic, the message's order will messup because rekeying results re-partinitong hence no gaurantee in the order.

I added below logic to achieve deduplication :
From **dedup-topic** create Ktable and Postgres table(using Sink connect). For each incoming message, check key (Msg Id + Action) in both Ktable and PG table.
If a record not found, that means it's not duplicated and write that record to dedup-topic.

But with the above message order is messing up due to rekeying /re-partitioning in **dedup-Topic.**

Please help how to achieve ordered msgs at this point?

Comment: Why you do `with re-keying to : Msg Id + Action`? It contains some business logic or transformation?

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding. Each ProgramUserId can have multiple messages and to avoid duplicate msgs, I am rekeying.